# Owl carousel fade not working with bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel-2

I have an owl carousel slider and I need fade effect. According to owl carousel doc, needs to add animate css library. So I have added it to my site. But it's not working at all. Seems all stacked behind each slide.

Here are my options for slider

```
$('.home-slider-2').owlCarousel({
    animateOut: 'slideOutDown',
    animateIn: 'flipInX',
    items:1,
    margin:30,
    stagePadding:30,
    smartSpeed:450
});
```

So I tried this way,

- Remove bootstrap 4 jQuery slim and add full version.
- Adjust smartSpeed:450 to higher

Still no any luck. Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jayD2/er9xnw7f/7/)

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `Owl carousel` uses the version `3.x` of `animate.css`. In the latest version of `animate.css (4.x)` we need to add `animate__animated` class to that element, we want to animate whereas in the version `3.x` we needed to add `animated` class to the element.

`Owl carousel` uses to automatically add the `animated` class and you just have to specify the animation you want.

#### Now, there are two ways to do it:

1. Either you change the link tag to:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" 
   href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css"/>
   ```

   From:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" 
   href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css">
   ```

2. Or Change the classes in the `js` according to the new version, like this:

   ```
   $(".home-slider-2").owlCarousel({
      animateOut: "animate__animated animate__slideOutDown",
      animateIn: "animate__animated animate__flipInX",
      items: 1,
      smartSpeed: 450
   });
   ```

Check it in action on Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/ZEBBXPw

---

**Note**

The `animate.css` file should be above the `Owl carousel` files.

---

You should use some better library to do so because even the [OwlCarousel2 GitHub](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2) says

> YEAH SO THIS IS PRETTY MUCH DEAD, DO YOURSELF A FAVOR AND SWITCH TO [tiny-slider](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider)

Answer (score 1):

To use Anime.css you need to add the following classes to the elements "animate_animated animate__(here goes your animation name)"

try something like this

```
animateOut: 'animate__animated animate__slideOutDown',
animateIn: 'animate__animated animate__flipInX',
```